# Semantics of header elements and WCAG 2.0

Tags: xhtml, header, accessibility, semantics, wcag

Am doing some accessibility testing on a site i am currently working on using Total Validator and the WAVE toolbar.

When using these it raises issues with the header structure of my documents and causes failures under **Guideline 1.3.1** - *Use structural markup in a way that does not represent relationships in the content*

http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/F43.html

I always understood that the most important heading on the page should be the h1 and that this heading does not always have to be the first heading on the page.

So for example i have a h2 in the masthead of the site which appears before the h1 in the markup.  However, even though the h2 appears prior to the h1 i would not say that it describes the page as well as the text i have marked up as a h1.

If i were to mark up the h2 as a h1 the most important heading throughout the site would only be contextual to the site and would not describe the page effectively.

I would have thought that this was not good practice for all manner of reasons e.g. SEO, Accessibility (Assistive technologies using headers to navigate through the site)

Am pretty sure that this is a case of pragmatism over validation.

Comment: Does the h2 in your masthead really need to be an h2 then? Maybe it could just be some other element like a span. Because I agree, the h1 should be specific to the page content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not clear you actually have a question there, but provided the content of the h2 is a header to *something*, in my opinion you're on pretty solid ground.

Do bear in mind that automated accessibility checkers are generally looking for suspicious patterns. It's quite rare that they can be absolutely certain that you are doing something wrong, so they should be used as a helper to find places which you can inspect manually to see if you could be marking up the content in a better way. Above all, remember that the ultimate goal is to make your site accessible to the widest possible user base, not to shut up an automated testing tool.